# Resources and guidelines on how to design large scale web-applications

Tags: database-design, data-modeling, restful-architecture, server-side-scripting

There is heaps of information (books, blogs, ...) on any aspect of web development available (html/css, database development, server-side logic and so on). Even books that cover all of these topics to get you started with your personal website asap. In times of high-speed internet access and contents easily going viral these days I am missing a good resource giving insights, best-practices and design guidelines of how to design large scale web applications that easily scale, featuring:

- efficient data modeling for databases
- spreading data across multiple (database or application) servers
- guidelines for efficient database queries
- how to automate server side processes (cron job design: how-to and which use cases are reasonable)
- caching: when and how?
- how to store/access millions of (user) images? database vs. harddisk? naming conventions?
- [...]

May seem very broad, yet relevant to anyone building an internet company, thus, facing exactly these issues sooner or later. Again, I am focussing on technological architecture issues rather than how to internally managing work processes as discussed here ([Larger Scale Web Project Planning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015328/larger-scale-web-project-planning)). Does anyone know good resources?

Answer (score 5):

I'll go out on a limb here and guess that you're not going to find a resource that covers the totality of your question because of the sheer size of the question would be thousands of pages.

So here are some quick recommendations to help you get started:

Data Modeling:

- The Data Model Resource Book, Vol. 1
- The Data Model Resource Book, Vol. 3
- Data and Reality

The first two books spend most of their contents describing some common modeling requirements and build progressively more advanced versions of the model. The end result isn't drop-in models for rapid development, but rather insight into what engineering trade-offs are made when complexity goes up. A good rule of thumb- Generic and Flexible Data models that support a wide range of scenarios tend to be more complicated and difficult to query. They should only be pursued if they provide tangible value to the business. Otherwise they become artificial complexity. The last book is older, and is more philosophical. It describes common modeling problems in applications and helps you think about them differently.

Spreading Data Across multiple servers:

- There are some very novel solutions to these problems, things like 'Datomic' come to mind, but assuming you want to stay with something commonly used like MySQL/PostgresSQL, I would focus less on 'splitting' the data stores and more on normalizing the data to reduce unnecessary redundancy. Eventually table partitioning may be used to help archive and alleviate troubling queries against large tables. Also, if you don't store assets in the database (images, et cetera) how likely is it that the database is going to be that large? Many modern databases have compressed data on disk, so a 500 GB database generally can store 1-2TB of customer information.
- SQL And the Relational Theory - C.J Date , excellent book on general relational theory.

Cron Jobs:
I would turn to the documentation for the database/operating systems you choose, PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, et cetera all have years of history running jobs against them in batch or on demand. Chances are good you're going to need 3 broad categories of routines:

- backup routines that run regularly.
- indexing routines that run hourly/nightly/weekly (depending on activity).
- consistency checks to make sure you don't have data corruption occurring.

You're also going to likely need something like an ETL tool or a scripting solution. I would recommend using a generic language (Python, Ruby, whatever) at first and then take specific portions and specialize them as requirements dictate. A good example is an ETL routine, at first running direct commands against your API might work fine, but eventually the scale may dictate a direct SQL solution.

As to patterns of use, I'd say that you want to have jobs that are idempotent, that way you can always run them without fear of consequence. This is more difficult than it sounds, but often leads to much better designs down the road. In fact, I'd argue that even your data model should try to be as non-destructive as possible. Rely on inserts and views to effect change, rather than delete/updates. Once your architecture relies on updates (or deletes), it's usually a good sign you're doing something that can get you into serious trouble if anything goes wrong.

Caching: This largely depends on what's required by your application. I would recommend looking into technologies like 'Memcached','indexed views', 'change data capture', or projects like 'apache samza'. Often requested but seldom changed information is usually the easiest to cache. Sometimes you can model data in such a way as to have older information in the cache, and then add the newest information from the live data store. That way you're not focused on pulling tons of information out of the operational database constantly, but rather just the latest information not present in the cache.

- Designing Data-Intensive Applications by Martin Kleppmann seems to cover some of these topics quite well. Although the full book is not available yet.

Storing / Access millions of images: I would lean against storing those in the database, and instead put them on the filesystem. The naming would likely have to be an unique key that could be safely combined with other files in a folder without fear of collision. Guids/Unique Identifiers are probably something to investigate. Operating system constraints probably matter as well here, some systems have very definite limits on files that can be stored in a single directory. Note that since the database is now effectively storing pointers to files, you have to treat operations against those files as transactions that happen in tandem with the database. storing them directly in the database is possible, but will make your database management harder. This is trade-off, are you more comfortable managing the operating system, or a complex database. If you do opt to put them in the database, I  would consider splitting the database files up so that core information (users, security, master data) are separate from the actual image data so that restores can bring the site online quickly and then back fill the images after core functionality is restored.

Other practical advice: focus on making your architecture and data model's as simple as possible to start with. It would be very easy to bog yourself down with an immensely complex data model and architecture only to discover that the elements that run the slowest have little to do with the design you ended up with. Another advantage of a simpler architecture is that it's easier to fit in your head at once. Scaling an architecture up/out is never going to be easy, but scaling a straight forward design (even if that means drastic changes) is definitely going to be easier than scaling a really complex one.

Comment: Thank you for your effort =) That was quite informative already. Well, I guess I just continue to crawl the web then...